# Pythonic way of ignoring an XML attribute if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, xml

I'm working on processing some XMLs from an API, however the XML is not as structured as I'd think. I've been struggling with just ignoring when an attribute's text doesn't exist.

I'm iterating trough my tree, getting each text and assigning them to a variable, e.g.:

```
codigo = produtos.find('sku').text
pais = produtos.find('attributes/country').text
```

and so on.

However, in some cases, the attributes child doesn't exist. I've attempted doing inline temporary expressions to just assign a blank value to the variables, but no matter what I do I get a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

For pais, sometimes this child doesn't exist, so I've attempted doing:

```
pais = produtos.find('attributes/country').text if produtos.find('attributes/country').text else ''
```

If I remove the `.text`call it will not retrieve the text when the attributes exist.

This seems really simple against what I'm doing as whole, but I just can't wrap my head around in fixing this issue. Is there a way to just ignore these inline when the attribute doesn't exist?

Comment: Hi @Lucas Neto. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079682/python-xml-parsing-if-an-element-doesnt-exist) can help you.

Comment: I did see that solution, however it doesn't fit my needs. I don't want to pass on my entire for loop, I want to define only that variable as NULL if the child doesn't exist, however I still want to be able to fetch other attributes inside the same tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching the most pythonic way I've found to do this inline is just suppressing the AttributeError (Python 3):

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(AttributeError): pais = produtos.find('attributes/country').text
```

Comment: How about "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission."? You could do eventually with try except. It's pythonic too. Anyway, glad you've found the answer.

Comment: I do agree with you that it's one way of doing it, also I'd much rather deal with the exception than simply suppress it, but I'm doing this for about 50 different attributes, so I'd end up with tons and tons of lines of code (and in this case I believe it would be slower due to the amount of records).